# Linq to SQL: how to aggregate without a group by?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am searching for the Linq-to-SQL equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT
  [cnt]=COUNT(*),
  [colB]=SUM(colB),
  [colC]=SUM(colC),
  [colD]=SUM(colD)
FROM myTable
```

This is **an aggregate without a group by**. I can't seem to find any way to do this, short of issuing four separate queries (one Count and three Sum). Any ideas?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is what I found seems like you still have to do a group by...can just use constant:

```
var orderTotals =
    from ord in dc.Orders
    group ord by 1 into og
    select new
    {
        prop1 = og.Sum(item=> item.Col1),
        prop2 = og.Sum(item => item.Col2),
        prop3 = og.Count(item => item.Col3)
    };
```

This produces the following SQL, which is not optimal, but works:

```
SELECT SUM([Col1]) as [prop1], SUM([Col2]) as [prop2], COUNT(*) AS [prop3]
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS [value], [t0].[Col1], [t0].[Col2], [t0].[Col3]
    FROM [table] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
GROUP BY [t1].[value]
```

Comment: How would this be translated to VB.Net? An error occurs on `group ord by 1 into og`. It doesn't like the 1.

Comment: @kaiyaq I translated it from C# to VB https://converter.telerik.com/ and got                      Dim orderTotals = db.Orders.GroupBy(Function(i) 1).[Select](Function(g) New With {Key
 .cnt = g.Count(), Key
    .ScolB = g.Sum(Function(item) item.ColB), Key
    .ScolC = g.Sum(Function(item) item.ColC)
}) which worked for me.

Answer (score 25):

You can do the same query using Lambda expression as follows:

```
  var orderTotals = db.Orders
                      .GroupBy( i => 1)
                      .Select( g => new
                      {
                           cnt = g.Count(), 
                           ScolB = g.Sum(item => item.ColB), 
                           ScolC = g.Sum(item => item.ColC) 
                      });
```

Comment: How do I use orderTotals cleanly in code?  Do I have to do a ToList() on the result and then check the list for a content of at least 1 and then use the first element in the list? Something like :        var list = orderTotals.ToList();     if(list.Count == 0) { return; } var totalColB = list[0].ScolB;     Is there a way I can change the query to return an object of the first result?  Or the complete result?