# Convert SQL query to linq to get max value

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT Max(VarInvoiceNo) FROM  tbl_feesCollection
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Linq to SQL, how do I find min and max of a column in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268175/using-linq-to-sql-how-do-i-find-min-and-max-of-a-column-in-a-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Max()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549271%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var result = db.tbl_feesCollection.Max(element => element.VarInvoiceNo);
```

Comment: var result = db.tbl_feesCollections.Max(element => element.VarInvoiceNo);   it's worked

Comment: @LEO221 did not know how you called your datacontext instance, updated my answer to match your `db`.