# SUM and COUNT in single LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create the following query in LINQ-TO-SQL.

```
select count(*), sum( o.CostInCents ) from Orders o
where Flag = true;
```

I came up with the following LINQ query:

```
var q = db.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Flag )

var result = q
    .GroupBy(o => 1)
    .Select(g => new MyDTO
    {
        NoOfOrders = g.Count(),
        TotalInCents = g.Sum(o => o.CostInCents )
    })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Is there a better way?

Is `.GroupBy(o => 1)` even OK?

The other option would be to do two queries, like below.

```
var q = db.Orders
   .Where(o => o.Flag );

//No groupBy
var result2 = new MyDTO
{
    NoOfCostedOrders = q.Count(),//hit the db
    TotalInCents = q.Sum(o => o.CostInCents )//hit the db 2nd time
};
```

How should I judge which approach is better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In terms of performance i suggest keeping the iqueryable as long as you can still filter, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1578977/3956100 other than that im not entirely sure what you want to accomplish with the code.

Comment: What is your grouping requirement for the Orders, not very clear, which property you want to use

Comment: It's ok. The trick is called **group by constant** and is the only LINQ way to produce multiple aggregates with single db query.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Just reviewed, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597181/linq-to-sql-how-to-aggregate-without-a-group-by,
 
looks like it is just to group all data as single unit, what's the benefit of doing so, we can't easily get the result without it.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Indeed it's just a way to transform a set to a single group. The benefit is to **allow** using multiple aggregate functions inside the LINQ query which has no grouping, hence normally produces a set.

Answer (score 4):

```
This query can be rewritten in sql format as follows

var orderList = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Flag );
var orderSummary = from o in orderList
                   group o by 1 into p
                   select new
                   {
                      Items = p.Count(),
                      Total = p.Sum( x => x.CostInCents)
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are searching for is the following slight adjustment:

```
var q = db.Orders
   .Where(o => o.Flag).Select(o => o.CostInCents).ToList(); // hit the db here once

//No groupBy
var result2 = new MyDTO
{
    NoOfCostedOrders = q.Count(), // don't hit the db
    TotalInCents = q.Sum() // don't hit the db a 2nd time
};
```

If you have a question to my adjustment feel free to comment.

Comment: very clever... I voted +1. However,  the problem is that if you have ten or hundred of thousands, it will return that many records which are bad - very bad. But man, you are thinking outside the box. I like it!