# How to do this query in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I need to do this query in ef core:

```
count(cmt.CaptureMethodId) as Total,
sum(case when DeactivateDate is null then 1 else 0 end) as Active,
sum(case when DeactivateDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) as Inactive
from [dbo].[CaptureMethodTerminals] cmt
join [dbo].[MerchantCaptureMethod] mcm
on cmt.CaptureMethodId = mcm.CaptureMethodId
where mcm.ClientMerchantId in ('00020', '00025')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SUM and COUNT in single LINQ to SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911445/sum-and-count-in-single-linq-to-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const ClientMerchantIds = new string[] {"00020", "00025"};
var cmt = dbContext.CaptureMethodTerminals.Where(x => ClientMerchantIds.Contains(x.CaptureMethod.ClientMerchantId));
var Total = cmt.Count();
var Active = cmt.Count(x => x.DeactivateDate == null);
var Inactive = cmt.Count(x => x.DeactivateDate != null);
```

Comment: Terrible, learn GroupBy by constant.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the pointer ^^ The answer was a joke to the poor question anyway, it is always nice to learn something new though!

Comment: Newbies get such solutions and put into real projects.

Comment: Not like the customer would care, but I get your point. I am looking into this right atm, willing to learn. I never claimed to be an expert, but newbies can learn from newbies ;-)

Comment: Actually question is not so bad, it is hard to make proper search request to find solution.