# Linq - Sum of values inside a select statement with joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have s select statement with joining 3 tables which returns something like salary of Individual employees, i want the sum of salary of all employees.

my statement looks like below.

This statement is returning array of Salaries of individual employees, how can i get the SUM ?

```
var x = (from e in EmpDB.Employees
      join d in EmpDB.Departments on e.DepId equals d.Id
      join s in EmpDB.EmpSalaries on new { d.Zone, d.Vendor, d.Status } equals new { s.Zone, s.Vendor, s.Status}
      where e.Status = "Active" && e.BAID != NULL && e.DepId == 3
      select new { s.Salary.Value });
```

Tried using SUM but not sure about it

Comment: Instead of posting the query you have. Could post a minimal example of your model classes, filled with only the important navigation properties?

Comment: related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597181/linq-to-sql-how-to-aggregate-without-a-group-by

Comment: tried using SUM in "select new { s.Salary.Value }) " but there is some issue

Comment: Anyway it is Entity Framework..

Comment: Are you asking for the sum of the salaries of **all** employees (which is what you ask for) or the sum of the salaries of the employees `where e.Status = "Active" && e.BAID != NULL && e.DepId == 3` (which is what your posted code is doing)? These are two very different things. It's important to be precise about exactly what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** to reflect Mindswipe's suggestion for more clarity.

The statement `select new { s.Salary.Value }` creates an enumerable collection of objects containing a salary value. To simplify this, we can instead use the following to create an enumerable collection of numeric values:

```
select s.Salary
```

Since you are using `.Value`, I assume that Salary is a nullable type meaning that we may get a null value in the set of salaries, so to avoid that, we will use the null coalescing operator `??` to return 0 for the null values:

```
select s.Salary ?? 0
```

Once you have a collection of the individual salary values, you can use the LINQ Sum function:

```
var x = (from e in EmpDB.Employees
      join d in EmpDB.Departments on e.DepId equals d.Id
      join s in EmpDB.EmpSalaries on new { d.Zone, d.Vendor, d.Status } equals new { s.Zone, s.Vendor, s.Status}
      where e.Status = "Active" && e.BAID != NULL && e.DepId == 3
      select s.Salary ?? 0)
      .Sum();
```

There are cleaner and more expressive ways to write this same query, but this should give you the result you are looking for.

Comment: assuming the type of `EmpDB.EmpSalaries.Salary.Value`. Perhaps it is nullable, perhaps it is a `string`, perhaps it is something else.

Comment: tried this but getting the compilation error - iqueryable<<anonymous type: int Value>> does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extenion method overload 'Queryable.Sum(IQueryable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'

Comment: Good answer. Great job catching the `select new { ...`. But this answer could be better by stating what was wrong and what you decided to change. Feel free to pirate my answer for this, you were here first

Comment: select s.Salary.value).sum() is getting the count value, but when there is null it is throwing an error, where as select s.Salary.GetValueOrDefault() is throwing an runtime error stating " linq to entities does not recognize the method 'int32 getvalueordefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a stored expression"

Comment: Understood. Can you try the null coalescing operator instead? I'll update the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies that you are selecting a new anonymous type, instead of just the salaries. All you have to do is change the last line from `select new { s.Salary.Value });`
 to `select s.Salary.GetValueOrDefault());` This will give you a list of whatever datatype `s.Salary` is (maybe a `double?`?)

So your query is now this:

```cs
var x = (from e in EmpDB.Employees
      join d in EmpDB.Departments on e.DepId equals d.Id
      join s in EmpDB.EmpSalaries on new { d.Zone, d.Vendor, d.Status } equals new { s.Zone, s.Vendor, s.Status}
      where e.Status = "Active" && e.BAID != NULL && e.DepId == 3
      select s.Salary.GetValueOrDefault());
```

---

For everyone who wants to use Expression LINQ here it is, for everyone who doesn't care you can stop reading.

```cs
var allSalaries = EmpDB.Employees.Join(EmpDB.Departments, employee => employee.DepId, department => department.Id,
        (employee, department) => new {Employee = employee, Department = department})
    .Join(EmpDB.EmpSalaries, emplDept => new
            {emplDept.Department.Status, emplDept.Department.Vendor, emplDept.Department.Zone}
        , emplSalary => new {emplSalary.Status, emplSalary.Vendor, emplSalary.Zone},
        (emplDept, emplSalary) => emplSalary.Salary).Sum();
```

Both queries aren't very readable as they are quite complex queries

Comment: select s.Salary.GetValueOrDefault()); is throwing an runtime error "linq to entities does not recognize the method 'int32 getvalueordefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a stored expression"

Comment: What datatype exactly is the Property `Salary` on `EmpDB.EmpSalaries`? I (and the other answer) assumed that it was just a nullable `int`